# Python 3.x short version of code

Tags: python

Is there a way shorter way to check for characters in a string? Thanks :D

```
check = input("Put in the letter: ")
word = "word"

if(check == word[0]):
    print(check)
if(check == word[1]):
    print(check)
if(check == word[2]):
    print(check)
if(check == word[3]):
    print(check)
```

Answer (score 5):

How about this:

```
if check in word:
    print(check)
```

Comment: It's not exactly the same, e.g. if `word = 'HELLO'` and `check = 'L'`

Answer (score 4):

Something like

```
for l in word:
      if l == check:
            print (check)
```

Maybe ?

Comment: Quick note: the code of @leistungsabfall will print the character once eventhough it might  occur multiple times, whereas my code like your original code prints n times if the letter occurs multiple times in the word.